# Standard SD card and Micro SD card with adapter; same speed?

Tags: speed, sd-card, adapter, micro-sd-card

I'm going to buy a new SD card to be used in my car's audio player. What I would like to know is, if I buy a micro SD card with adapter, will it provide the same read/write speed as a standard SD card of the same model? Does using adapter affect speed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The adapter is basically just a bunch of wires; they use the same signaling. The class of the device will determine the speed, not the adapter.

Answer (score 6):

As far as my experience goes, there's no difference between using an SD card vs a micro SD card.

I've even booted full linux distributions from a micro-sd card (8GB) with a SD adapter